# Bug with google Chrome in select

Tags: html, css

In the last update of Chrome, some HTML instruction was changed that changed the interpretation of the "select" component.
Any idea how to fix this? It only happens in this latest version of Chrome (59.0.3071.115).
[my combo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCfo2.jpg)

Comment: Can you post some of your CSS and HTML? Just updated to the same version and my select boxes seem to work the same as before the update.

Comment: I have another project that uses bootstrap and gave the same "problem".
It is a simple HTML, with nothing special.

Comment: Went to a bootstrap site too, no changes there either. I'm having issues reproducing your problem. I see your issue is not unique https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2017/06/stable-channel-update-for-desktop_26.html but it's hard to see what you're doing differently without some context (classes, whitespace, js plugins, etc)

Comment: We cannot help you unless you post a [mcve] in your question

Answer (score 0):

Here my Code:

```
        <select id="SelectTest">
            <option value="A">Item A</option>
            <option value="B">Item B</option>
            <option value="C">Item C</option>
            <option value="D">Item D</option>
        </select>
```

See the difference between my computer and my DEV environment (accessing through Citrix). The two with the same version.

[Difference in items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPHgb.jpg)